# How to open a program in CMD and interact with it with Java

Tags: java, cmd, process, runtime

I am able to open some program, that can get instructions from cmd to do some stuff, like opening file with certain arguments, check if it's ready, etc...

That's how I open file through Java.

```
final String location = "C:\\Program";
final File dir = new File(location);
String cmd = "cmd.exe /c start my-program.exe";         
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null , dir);
```

**How do I interact with it now**, send commands like "check_status" or "do_some_stuff" and get it's output to Java.

If I try this:

```
String [] cmd = {"cmd.exe /c start my-program.exe", "do_stuff"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null , dir);
```

I get error: "Cannot run program "cmd.exe /c start my-program.exe.exe" (in directory "C:\Program"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

But it does finds file when I send single String as an argument.

I understand that I can get it's output to Java this way:

```
java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);   
}
```

**EDIT:** Solved by using getOutputStream.

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
        w.write("custom_command");
        w.close();
```

Comment: And you send commands by writing them to `process.getOutputStream()`, though you might not be able to, since you used the `start` command, so don't do that, just run the .exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

I started Wildfly server with standalone.bat file(similar .exe file)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd D:\\Users\\turack\\Downloads\\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\\bin\\ && standalone.bat");
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using getOutputStream.

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
        w.write("custom_command");
        w.close();
```